# linux command to connect to another server using hostname and port number

Tags: linux

what is the Linux command to connect to another server using host name and port number?

how to connect to another server using only host name and port number then check if an existing process is running? the only way i see it working is to log in to the server and run the `PS` command. but is there a way to do it without logging in directly to the other server and connect only with host name and port number and check the running process?

Comment: Connecting to a machine requires using a particular protocol. There is no such thing as "just connecting." Running `ps` over SSH like you were doing sounds like a good way.

Comment: Do you know the port? it will be helpful for us to infer which protocol and thus the program for you to use.

Comment: @Dark Falcon yeah im using `SSH2` to connect to other servers and with credentials to login but what if i dont have a credential and just have the host name and port number?

Comment: Then you can't do it. You need credentials, either username and password or a key pair.

Comment: @eri answer should do it. Telnet to the port. ie. `telnet hostname port` and if it connects then your service is listening. Unless there is a firewall blocking the port of course.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to try an arbitrary connection to a given host/port combination, you could try one `nmap`, `telnet` or `nc` (netcat).

Note that you can't necessarily determine whether or not a process is running remotely - it might be running on that port, but simply ignore anything it sees over the port. To really be sure, you will need to run `ps` or `netstat` or etc. via `ssh` or etc.

If you want to use SSH from e.g. a script or, more generally, without typing in login information, then you will want to use public key authentication. Ubuntu has some good documentation on how to set this up, and it's very much applicable to other distrobutions as well: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys.

If you have no access to the server you're trying to list processes on at all, then I'm afraid there isn't a way to list running processes remotely (besides remote tools like `nmap` and so on, as mentioned earlier - you can always probe public ports without authentication [although you might make people angry if you do this to servers you don't own]). This is a feature, not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

`telnet` connects to most of services. With it you can ensure that port is open and see hello message (if any). Also `nc` is more low level.

```
eri@eri-macro ~ $ telnet smtp.yandex.ru 25
Trying 87.250.250.38...
Connected to smtp.yandex.ru.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp16.mail.yandex.net ESMTP (Want to use Yandex.Mail for your domain? Visit http://pdd.yandex.ru)
helo
501 5.5.4 HELO requires domain address.
HELO ya.ru
250 smtp16.mail.yandex.net
MAIL FROM: <someusername@somecompany.ru>
502 5.5.2 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
```

If there is plain text protocol you cat talk with service by keyboard. If connection is secured try openssl.

```
openssl s_client -quiet -connect www.google.com:443
depth=1 /C=ZA/O=Thawte Consulting (Pty) Ltd./CN=Thawte SGC CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0

GET /

<HTML><HEAD>
```

If protocol is not known you may see much of hieroglyphs  or just `Connected to ...` message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
ssh <YOUR_HOST_NAME> 'ps auxwww'
```

Like Dark Falcon said in the comments, you need a protocol to communicate with the server, a port alone is useless in this case.

By default on unix (and unix like) servers, [ssh](/questions/tagged/ssh) is the way to go.

Comment: yeah i think `ssh` works but what if i dont have a credential...analogous to Windows what i am trying to achieve here is like this command `tasklist /S SYSTEM`

Comment: You can use SSH without entering any login credentials using public key authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Remote Shell with this command.  Example is cat a file on the remote machine.

**rsh host port 'cat remotefile' >> localfile**

**host** and **port** self explainitory

**remotefile**: name of some file on the machine remote logging to in home directory

**localfile**: name of file cat information to.

Comment: I would argue that `rsh` is a bad option because `ssh` provides all of its functionality, while avoiding sending unencrypted data over a network.

Answer (score 0):

Use monitoring software (like Nagios). It looks at your processes, sensors, load and thatever you configured to watch. It continuously stores log. It alerts you by email\sms\jabber if something fails. You can access it with browser or by HTTP API.